# Hadoop FileSystem.mkdirs(path, permission) ignores the permission

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create directory in hdfs programatically. I need the directory to be writable for all users. So I try to pass the perissions to mkdirs like this:

```
Path dir = new Path("/tmp/mkdir-test");    
fileSystem.mkdirs(dir, new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL));
```

however, the result is that I get directory with `drwxr-xr-x` permission. This does not seem to be some overall permission issue, because if I do set them explicitly at next line:

```
// For some reason the initial permissions are ignored
fileSystem.setPermission(dir, new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL));
```

the directory ends up properly with `drwxrwxrwx` as intended.

Why are the permissions passed to `mkdirs` not honored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the javadoc of the actual method not mentioning anything, there is static method `FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem, Path, FsPermission)` which provides some explanation:

> Create a directory with the provided permission.
>   The permission of the
>   directory is set to be the provided permission as in setPermission,
>   not permission&~umask.

So it turns out that standard `mkdirs` ANDs the given permission with umask.

The static utility method is implemented as combination of `mkdirs` and `setPermission`